# Are all "GET" requests to JSF "Initial Request"s?

Tags: jsf

In JSF 1.1, I am assuming that GET requests are treated as initial requests (resulting in the creation of a new view), and POST requests are treated as Postbacks (resulting in the restoration of the old view).

However, my application is behaving differently - it restores the same old view even for GET requests. Why does this happen? Is there a way to force the creation of a new view for GET requests?

(My state-saving method is 'server'. I'm using MyFaces with JSP, and I have a t:saveState on a managed bean in the view)

Regards,

Pradyumna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describes is indeed true for legacy JSF 1.0/1.1 and has been improved ("fixed") in JSF 1.2.

JSF 1.2 is already there since early 2006 (>4 years ago). Why don't you upgrade?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it clear.. do you mean that in JSF 1.1, GET requests result in restoration of the old view (if one exists), and in JSF 1.2, GET requests always result in creation of a new one?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try upgrading to 1.2